# C# Adding string into listview, causes error?

Tags: c#, json

So I have an piece of code here:

```
dynamic getPoints = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Profile.Profile.Currency.ToString());
var Points = getPoints[1].amount;
addItems(Username, Password, Points);
```

addItems Void

```
info.Text = Username;
info.SubItems.Add(Password);
info.SubItems.Add(Points);
listView1.Items.Add(info);
```

Problem:

So after I call this & it tries to do addItems, then this error appears:

> The best overloaded method match for ProgramTest.Form1.addItems(string, string string) has some invalid arguments.

How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddItems()` doesn't take a `dynamic`. Solution: don't use `dynamic` and instead properly convert your JSON data into real types. Use `JToken.Parse()`. For example:

```
var json = JArray.Parse(Profile.Profile.Currency.ToString());
var Points = json[1].Value<string>("amount");
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to google yeah how to do without dynamic sadly I didn't find any solution. At the moment I am receiving this error: http://prntscr.com/bzmfjl

Comment: Oh god I forgot about index(es) xD

Answer (score 0):

One or more of your arguments to addItems is not a string. Find out which ones they are, and add ToString() to the parameter name(s). If that results in incorrect formatting, post what you get and we will try to help you further.

Comment: Post the signature of your addItems method.

Comment: Sorry? I didn't understand :/